# Morphia + GWT issue

Tags: mongodb, maven, gwt, morphia

I have simple gwt maven project and I use morphia.
I know that I must use dto objects in purposes of the client compilation code, because its not possible to use entityes in the client code?!Is that the right way?
So I have DTO in my shared folder and morphia Entity in my server folder.

Is there any way to use the entity class in the shared folder ?
Because when I'm trying to do so I have [ERROR] Line 22: No source code is available for type ****** did you forget to inherit a required module?

Thanks

Comment: Does your .gwt.xml file contain the entry for <source path='shared' />. If so then you should be able to put your DTO's in the shared folder. If not then they would need to be somewhere in the client package.

Comment: Yes , I have <source path='shared' /> but it's not a problem in the DTO. The problem is when I'm trying to use some morphia entity in the shared or client packages.
For exemple when I do so in the DTO constructor
public ObjectDto(ObjectEntity entity){...}